# Different between "Assign IP by AWS" and "Use Elastic IP" in network load balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I don't know the purpose of using "Elastic IP" in load balancing.
Why don't we use "Assign IP by AWS" to allow AWS generated random IP in network balancing ?
Because we use DNS to access the website rather than using IP to access
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often it is mostly because they need an IP address that doesn’t change.
The load balancer can go down, it often doesn't always happen, but there is a possibility. If it does go down, the random IP address might change, meaning your DNS no longer points to the previous IP address.

So, often, using an elastic IP address that is static is great.

Answer (score 1):

Some people want to use a **static IP address** for their resources (such as the Load Balancer).

This is common where an organization wants to whitelist a specific address in their firewall. They want a **static IP address** (which is provided by an Elastic IP) instead of a random IP address.